# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure with Yarn and Docker

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, docker

I developed a Spark application on local and got no problems. But when I wanted to push it in a Yarn Cluster in a docker Image, I got the following messages :

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 26, sandbox): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 lost)
>   Driver stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
>       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>   uote

The command used to launch the app is:

```
spark-submit --class myapp.myapp_spark.App --master yarn-client /opt/myapp/myapp_spark.jar
```

My application is using a Mongo database. Is it linked to a memory problem, to the connection with Mongo or something else ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I got this error due to a memory problem on the Yarn Cluster. The Master machine hadn't enough memory available (RAM). I used the same cluster, but make more place in memory (4go) and now it's working well !